Terraform dynamically passing a block
I need help with dynamically populating a field from a json where the field is a block in terraform definition.
I am referring to https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/aws/latest/docs/resources/bedrockagent_knowledge_base#rds_configuration-block.
The field_mapping block will have different columns and values for each json object.
{ 
  "team1": {
    "name": "test1",
    "owner": "Michael",
    "env": "stg",
    "role_arn": "aws:arn::xxxxxxx",
    "field_mapping": {
      "column1": "value1",
      "column2": "value2"
    }
  },
  "team2": {
    "name": "test2",
    "owner": "David",
    "env": "stg",
    "role_arn": "aws:arn::xxxxxxx",
    "field_mapping": {
      "column1": "value1",
      "column2": "value2",
      "column3": "value3",
      "column4": "value4",
      "column5": "value5"
    
    }
  }
}

Terraform block, where field_mapping block needs to be dynamically populated.
resource "aws_bedrockagent_knowledge_base" "example" {
  for_each = { for team, values in local.config : team => values}
  name     = each.key
  role_arn = each.value.role_arn

  knowledge_base_configuration {
    vector_knowledge_base_configuration {
      embedding_model_arn = "arn:aws:bedrock:us-west-2::foundation-model/amazon.titan-embed-text-v1"
    }

    type = "VECTOR"
  }

  storage_configuration {
    type = "RDS"

    rds_configuration {
      collection_arn    = "arn:aws:aoss:us-west-2:123456789012:collection/142bezjddq707i5stcrf"
      vector_index_name = "bedrock-knowledge-base-default-index"

      field_mapping {
        ### I need all columns as per json
      }
    }
  }
}


It would make your much life simpler if you could convert the json string to a format that Terraform understands, otherwise you must parse the json string "manually".
Also, field_mapping should be converted to an array where each element corresponds to a field, instead of adding custom properties like columnX for each one.

Thanks @RuiJarimba. I modified json as you suggested and made it array. This is my modified code looks like now and failing with syntax issues. I need quick correction on the dynamic block probably ?
dynamic "field_mapping" {
for_each = { for mapping in each.value.field_mapping : mapping.column => mapping.value }
content {
field_mapping.key => field_mapping.value
}
}
}
}
}

Please edit your question and add more details - for example, how is local.config defined?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

@Divyap what were the errors when you changed the code? We need to see them to be able to provide more help.

According to the documentation, field_mapping has a fixed set of four arguments metadata_field, primary_key_field, text_field, and vector_field, and so it isn't clear to me how your "field_mapping" property -- written as a mapping from column name to value -- could be translated into what the provider expects. What is the rule for deciding which of the column names to include in each of the four arguments? You also only have two columns in the first example, which isn't enough to populate the four required fields of field_mapping.
